# Problem with opening chromium tabs

Tags: chromium

I want to open 2 chromium tabs using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

#chromium is not open

chromium-browser 'www.amazon.com' 
sleep 2
chromium-browser 'www.ebay.com' 
sleep 2
```

It opens the first tab but in order to open the second tab I have to manually close chromium or else it will not continue. Why is this happening? I do not want the tabs to open at the same time and that is why I put 'sleep' in between the chromium-browser commands. The browser is originally closed. If the browser is open then the tabs open the way I want them to.

edit: I'm using ubuntu 16.04

edit2: I simplified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to add an `&` and the end of `chromium-browser 'www.amazon.com'`.

The `&` informs the shell to put the command in the background, your shellscript should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

chromium-browser 'www.amazon.com'&
sleep 2
chromium-browser 'www.ebay.com'&
sleep 2
```

You have to send the task to the background because otherwise the terminal can not execute the commands after your first call to`chromium-browser 'www.amazon.com'`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. Can you explain it to me a little bit more? Why does it have to be run by the background? Why is the terminal frozen after the first call of the browser?

Comment: Because, if you don't send your process to background, the terminal keeps waiting until the process exit, during this time the terminal will print some logs of the program. That's why you had to close chromium-browser before, in order to continue executing your script. You can find more info about this topic here:  [How To Use Bash's Job Control to Manage Foreground and Background Processes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes)